# Modifying a dataframe with day offset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timezone-offset

I am dealing with a very large size dataframe. A small sample is in bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'nodes': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'dept': ['20:00', '02:00', '21:00'],
                   'arrv': ['20:00', '17:00', '21:00'],
                   'dept_offset_day': [0, 1, 0],
                   'arrv_offset_day': [0, 1, 0],
'stop_num':[0,1,2]})
print(df)
 nodes   dept   arrv  dept_offset_day  arrv_offset_day
0     A  20:00  20:00                0                0
1     B  02:00  17:00                1                1
2     C  21:00  21:00                0                0
```

I am trying to 1) add a date into the start and end time by considering the day offsets. 2) break nodes column to two nodes_start and nodes_end columns i.e points to points. Something like:

```
nodes_start   nodes_end       start_datetime       end_datetime 
     A           B           2019-5-9 20:00           2019-5-10 02:00     
     B           C           2019-5-10 17:00          2019-5-10 21:00
```

I tried using pd.offsets.Day() and loop through each line, but it makes the exec time very slow and I get wrong dates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: where are you getting the date part in your 2nd code block?

Comment: it is just adding now() to the time.

Comment: how do you determine which node is start and which is end? or should we just assume top to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing a new data-frame, with new columns (copied columns really :D):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['nodes_start'] = df['nodes'][:2]
df2['nodes_end'] = df['nodes'][-2:].reset_index(drop=True)
df2['start_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrv'][:2])
df2['end_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dept'][-2:].reset_index(drop=True))
df2['start_datetime'] = [df2['start_datetime'][0] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)] + [df2['start_datetime'][1]]
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  nodes_start nodes_end      start_datetime        end_datetime
0           A         B 2019-05-09 20:00:00 2019-05-10 02:00:00
1           B         C 2019-05-10 17:00:00 2019-05-10 21:00:00
```